# Passing a token through Query?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I have a Graph QL server running (Apollo Server 2) and the API behind it requires every request to include a token.

Currently the token comes from HTTP Request Cookie. This was simple enough to work. When the request comes in, grab the cookie from the header and pass it along to the HTTP request to be sent to the API server through the resolvers.

I'd like to make it so a GraphQL client can pass this token along through the POST query itself.

Basically wondering if I can define a global GQL variable of some sort. "All queries, this variable is required."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar implementation in Typescript, and in order to achieve something like this, I've define an object:

```
const globalInput = {
   token: {
     type: GraphQLString;
   }
}
```

And then use it in your GraphQLObjectType:

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
        myObject: {
          type: MyTypeObject,
          args: { ...globalInput },
          resolve: (source: any, args: any) => {
             // global input values can be access in args
             // ex: args.token
             return {}
          }
        }
    })
})
```

The problem is that I need to extend it(`...globalInput`) it in every object type.
But it does the job.